# Grouping, Filtering and Navigation in WPF DataGrid bound to observableCollection

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

If i have my WPF DataGrid bound to ObservableCollection in the ViewModel (it is a requirement), how can i implement Grouping, Filtering and Navigation which can be done directly if DataGrid was bound to CollectionView.
IS it possible to get the benefits of both types of collections in the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView` method inside of your ViewModel so that you can Access SortDescription, GroupDescription and Filter Property of the Collection View

Usage

```
  var cv = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Customers);
```

Comment: in this case i have to bind my DataGrid to CollectionView so i will loss capabilities provided by binding to ObservableCollection and this the problem.

Comment: if you use the snippet i wrote it will return the CollectionView you are binding to.